How can I identify each square separately?
I'm trying to create a minesweeper game, and I need to be able to pick out a single square.
from tkinter import *
import random

startX = 0
startY = 0

game = Tk()

game.geometry('600x600')
game.title('Simon')
canvas = Canvas(game, width=600, height=600, bg='#13cce7')

canvas.pack()

for j in range(4):
    for i in range(4):
        tile = canvas.create_polygon(startX, startY, startX+150, startY, startX+150, startY+150, startX, startY+150, fill="grey", outline="black", width="5")
        startY = startY+150
    startY = 0
    startX = startX+150



You'd probably need to store all squares in an array, when clicking a square you send the index to a function.  You also should consider pygame

Look into the tag/id system for tkinter Canvas. Basically you can put tags on the rectangles and identify them using that tag. Alternatively you can use your tile variables (using a list probably) to identify the individual squares.

It is not clear what you want.  In what situation you want to identify each square? When user clicks on any square? By specifying coordinates, i.e. (x, y)? So it is better to provide a [mre] on how you want to identify the square and what problem you come across.

As David suggested in the comment for your question, I demonstrate the usage of a list of rectangles (suggested by TheLizzard):
from tkinter import *

startX = 0
startY = 0

game = Tk()

game.geometry('600x600')
game.title('Simon')
canvas = Canvas(game, width=600, height=600, bg='#13cce7')

canvas.pack()

tiles = [[canvas.create_rectangle(x * 150, y * 150, x * 150 + 150, y * 150 + 150, fill="grey", outline="black", width="5") for x in range(4)] for y in range(4)]

for row in tiles:
    for tile in row:
        canvas.tag_bind(tile, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event, tile=tile: event.widget.itemconfig(tile, fill="red"))
        canvas.tag_bind(tile, "<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, tile=tile: event.widget.itemconfig(tile, fill="grey"))

game.mainloop()

You can replace lambda function with any other function in your mind

A solution to that
e.g (the comments are there to better clarify)
from tkinter import *

def on_click(event):
    # Get the coordinates of the click (call back function)
    x, y = event.x, event.y

    # Determine the row and column based on the coordinates
    col = x // 150
    row = y // 150

    # Check if the click is within the bounds of the grid
    if (row, col) in tiles:
        tile_id = tiles[(row, col)]
        # Change the color of the clicked tile (for demonstration)
        canvas.itemconfig(tile_id, fill='red')
        print(f"Tile clicked: Row {row}, Column {col}")

# Initialize the game window
game = Tk()
game.geometry('600x600')
game.title('Simon')
canvas = Canvas(game, width=600, height=600, bg='#13cce7')
canvas.pack()

# Create the tiles and store their IDs in a dictionary
tiles = {}
startX, startY = 0, 0

for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        tile_id = canvas.create_polygon(
            startX, startY, startX + 150, startY, startX + 150, startY + 150, startX, startY + 150,
            fill="grey", outline="black", width="5"
        )
        tiles[(row, col)] = tile_id
        startX += 150
    startX = 0
    startY += 150

# Bind the click event to the on_click function
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)

# Start the main event loop
game.mainloop()

The randomness, or the sweeping per say, you can adapt into the code.

Not the best performing piece of code, however, it sets the tiles apart, making them clickable and giving the dev more control over them.

This short code responds to user interaction using canvas.bind on button press and release. It only responds to ButtonPress-1 when mouse pointer is still in the same square on ButtonRelease-1, giving a positive selection.
from tkinter import *

startX = startY = 0

game = Tk()

game.geometry('600x600')
canvas = Canvas(game, width=600, height=600, bg='#13cce7')
canvas.pack()

# include activefill color 'red'
for j in range(4):
    for i in range(4):
        tile = canvas.create_polygon(
            startX, startY, startX+150, startY, startX+150, startY+150, startX, startY+150,
            fill="grey", outline="black", activefill = "red", width="5")
        startY = startY+150
    startY = 0
    startX = startX+150
    
def actionPress(event):
    canvas.itemPress = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]

def actionRelease(event):
    canvas.itemRelease = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    if canvas.itemPress == canvas.itemRelease:
        print(canvas.itemRelease, canvas.type(canvas.itemRelease))

# Bind Button-1 for positive response to clicking in a specific square.
# A ButtonPress-1 in one square and ButtonRelease-1 in another square will NOT cause a response.
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", actionPress)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", actionRelease)

game.mainloop()

